# how to dynamically divide object properties in columns in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

So I have an object like below -

```
const characters = [
    {
      name: "Thor",
      universe: "Marvel",
      remarks:"hvdufdjfkjdnfkjdnfkjndkfndkjnfdkjnfkjdnfkj"
      type: "God",
    },
    {
      name: "Batman",
      universe: "DC",
      remarks:"hvdufdjfkjdnfkjdnfkjndkfndkjnfdkjnfkjdnfkj"
      type: "Human",
    },
    {
      name: "Iron man",
      universe: "Marvel",
      remarks:"hvdufdjfkjdnfkjdnfkjndkfndkjnfdkjnfkjdnfkj"
      type: "Human",
    },
  ];
```

Currently, it is getting displayed like this using the below code-

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Image from 'next/image';

const characters = [
  {
    name: 'Thor',
    universe: 'Marvel',
    remarks: 'hvdufdjfkjdnfkjdnfkjndkfndkjnfdkjnfkjdnfkj',
    type: 'God',
  },
  {
    name: 'Batman',
    universe: 'DC',
    remarks: 'hvdufdjfkjdnfkjdnfkjndkfndkjnfdkjnfkjdnfkj',
    type: 'Human',
  },
  {
    name: 'Iron man',
    universe: 'Marvel',
    remarks: 'hvdufdjfkjdnfkjdnfkjndkfndkjnfdkjnfkjdnfkj',
    type: 'Human',
  },
];

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {characters.map((character, index) => (
        <div>
          {!!index && (
            <hr
              className="w-full my-4"
              style={{ border: '1px solid #BEC3C8' }}
            />
          )}
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-30 gap-y-6">
            {Object.entries(character).map(([key, value]) => (
              <div className="flex flex-col">
                <div className="font-bold">{key}</div>
                <div className="whitespace-pre-wrap break-words">{value}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

What I want is that **remarks** should take the full space or width instead of getting divided into two columns with **type** property.

So, it should be like **name** and **universe** in the first row, then **remarks** in the second row, then **type** in the third row and **remarks** should take the full width.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know anything about tailwind-css, but `class="basis-full"` seems like a possibility (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-basis). Use an if-statement (or a ternary operator) within `Object.entries(character).map` to determine which class to use (i.e. `if (key === "remarks"){/* Do stuff here*/}`).

Comment: @EmilKarlsson I am using Grid outside and basis-full is not working... can you please tell me how to do it in vanilla css.

Comment: In vanilla html (not even any css needed), you would create a table and just add `colspan="2"` to the `td` that you want to have fill up 2 columns of space. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_colspan